# How do I get the sum with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

Here is a table I have got:

```
ID  Name        Tid Quality     Quantity

40  903.02481-A.GEO 6   St3s        2   
41  903.02481-A.GEO 6   St3s        1   
42  903.02509-A.GEO 6   ST3S        1   
43  903.02942-A.GEO 6   ST3S        2   
44  903.02942-A.GEO 6   ST3S        4   
45  923.00186-B.GEO 6   ST3S        3   
46  924.03020-B.GEO 6   ST3S        1   
47  924.03021-A.GEO 6   ST3S        1   
48  924.03021-A.GEO 6   ST3S        1   
49  924.04082-C.GEO 6   ST3S        1
```

What I need is:

```
40  903.02481-A.GEO 6   St3s        **3**   
42  903.02509-A.GEO 6   ST3S        1   
43  903.02942-A.GEO 6   ST3S        **6**   
45  923.00186-B.GEO 6   ST3S        3   
46  924.03020-B.GEO 6   ST3S        1   
47  924.03021-A.GEO 6   ST3S        **2**   
49  924.04082-C.GEO 6   ST3S        1
```

How to write LINQ query to get this?

Comment: What are the rules and what have you tried?

Comment: Use `GroupBy` and `Sum`. Enough?

Comment: I have to sum over quantity

Comment: I am novice to LINQ, dont know how to start

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to `SUM` the `Quantity` of the groups with the same `Name`:

```
var result = list
     .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
     .Select(g => new {
        ID = g.First().ID,
        Name = g.Key,
        Tid = g.First().Tid,
        Quality = g.First().Quality,    
        Quantity = g.SUm(x => x.Quantity))
     });
```